# Query Optimization and profiling for celery tasks

Tags: django, django-orm, django-celery, django-debug-toolbar, django-silk

Django-debug-toolbar and Django-silk are two famous tools for profiling HTTP requests. Is it possible to analyze a celery task or any other function inside the code?
for instance, I have a celery task like this:

```
def main_task():
    while _condition:
        logic()
        sleep(_t)
    return True
```

I need some information like duplicate and similar queries in `logic()` for every loop.